# Pine Script - drawing line between different corners of bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hi it is possible to draw a trand line which connectes top right corner of a certain body bar to another top right corner of a another body bar?

Currently im able to draw this line between the middle top of the candle body to another middle top of a candle bar using this code:

```
candle1_x = bar_index[1]  // X-coordinate is one bar ago
candle1_y = high[1]      // Y-coordinate is the high of the first candle

// Define the coordinates of the second candle
candle2_x = bar_index    // X-coordinate is the current bar
candle2_y = high        // Y-coordinate is the high of the current candle

// Plot the trend line
line.new(x1=candle1_x, y1=candle1_y, x2=candle2_x, y2=candle2_y, color=color.blue)
```

I didnt find any way to achive my desired result. Does anyone knows how to achive it?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You cannot be that precise on the x-axis. It will always draw from the mid of the bar.

Comment: Do you know any other way to make an indicator using maybe js to achive this goal?

Comment: Nope, not possible.